# What is the indecomposable decomposition of holomorphic differentials of an Artin-Schreier curve C as a Z/p-representation?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory, ramification

I am attempting to decompose the holomorphic differentials of an Artin-Schreier-Witt curve as a $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$-representation. This is done in Theorem 1 of Madan-Valentini [Automorphisms and holomorphic differentials in characteristic p](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X81900329). However, I seem to be unable to understand their result even in the simplest case ($n=1, p=3$).

First, I will define the quantities that show up in their theorem.

$F$ is the function field of the curve with affine model $y^3-y = x^2$. $E$ is $K(x)$ the function field of $P^1$. They use the notation $\Omega_F:= H^0(C, \Omega_C)$.

In our example, we have just one ramified prime $P'$ (the elliptic curves point at infinity) which is totally ramified over the point $P$ (infinity on the projective line).

In our case, $r = 0$. [[This is because $r := 1 - max(e_i)$, where $e_i$ is the ramification index of all primes $P_i$ in $F$ which ramify over $P$ in $E$, and $e_i = 1$, thus, $r = 0$.]]

Further, $\Gamma_k := v_{ik} := \lfloor \frac{d(P'|P) + kv_{P'}(x^2)}{p} \rfloor$, where $d(P'|P)$ is the exponent of the different of the point $P'$ over the point $P$.

Their theorem is as follows:

[image]

---

What I know is true:

In our example, there is only one degree 1 component when considering $H^0(C, \Omega_C)$ as a $Z/3$-representation, and no other components. This degree 1 component is generated by $dy/x$. As a sanity check, we know apriori that the holomorphic differentials of C coincide with the cotangent space of the Jacobian at its origin, that is $H^0(C, \Omega_C) \simeq T^*_e(Jac(C))$, so it should indeed be 1-dimensional since $Jac(C)$ of an elliptic curve $C$ is 1-dimensional.

---

Madan-Valentini result:

The two values that go into the definition of $\Gamma_{k+1} := v_{1k}$ in Theorem 1 are **(1)** $d(P'|P)$ the exponent of the different of the point $P$ at infinity in $K(x)$ wrt the point $P'$ at infinity in the elliptic curve, and **(2)** the valuation of $x^2$ at the point $P'$ in the elliptic curve totally ramified above infinity.

I calculated that **(1)** is 6, and **(2)** is 6 also.

Plugging in my values of **(1)** and **(2)**, I get $v_{11} = 0$ and, $v_{12} = -2$.

But!! But, having only 1 degree one component in the representation forces the values of $\Gamma_0 := v_{11}$ and $\Gamma_1 := v_{12}$ in their theorem to have the relation $v_{11} = v_{12} + 1$.  I can't find my error, however! It's driving me up the wall!

**Here's my question: What have I done wrong? Why am I getting a contradiction?**

I will explain how I calculated **(1)** and **(2)**, I hope that someone can spot an error. The method of calculating (2) was explained to me by Jora Belousov, and all errors are mine and mine alone.

**(1)** calculation of the exponent of the different $d(P'|P)$

The only ramification point is at infinity which I'll call $P := (1/x)$. We consider a valuation $v_P$ on $K(x)$. If the $x$-valuation of $w \in K(x)$ is nonpositive, then $v_P(x^2 - (w^p-w)) = v_P(x^2) = -2$. If the $x$-valuation of $w$ is positive, then $v_P (x^2 - (w^p-w)) = v_P(w^p) = p v_P (w)$ which is negative and less than $-p$, so the answer is $-2$ and it is well-defined. Thus, we have that our jump at $P$ is $m_P = 2$.

Here I am using Stichtenoth, Algebraic Function Fields and Codes, Thm 3.7.8. We may then immediately calculate the exponent of the different $d(P'|P) = (p-1)(m_P + 1)$, i.e., 2*3 = 6.

**(2)** calculation of $v_{P'}(x^2)$ (which is called $-\Phi(1, 1)$ in Valentini-Madan)

Let $v_{P'}$ be the valuation extending the valuation at infinity of the projective line, which we've called $v_P$.

First, we homogenize the equation $x^2 = y^3 - y$:

and get $x^2z = y^3 - yz^2$.

Then, we go to the chart $x = 1$, in this chart, the function $f=x^2$ becomes $f = 1/Z^2$. Here, our equation becomes $Z = Y^3-YZ^2$ which implies $$Z = Y^3/(YZ + 1).$$

We now localize the coordinate ring $K[Y,Z]/(Y^3 - YZ^2 - Z)$ at the point $(Y = 0, Z=0)$, let's call that ring $A_P$. Since $(YZ+1)$ doesn't vanish at this point, it is a unit in $A_P$. Thus, $Z$ is contained in the ideal generated by $Y$. Because the maximal ideal of the local ring $A_P$ is the principal ideal of $Y$, the valuation that we are interested in can be computed as the $Y$-degree: $v_(Y,Z) = v_Y$. Again using the elliptic curve equation, we may express our original $f = x^2$ in our new coordinates as $f = (1/Z)^2 = (YZ+1)^2/Y^6$.

Thus, $v_{P'}(x^2) = v_{(Y,Z)}(Z^{-2}) = v_{Y} (Y^{-6}) = -6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy Booher for explaining the following in private correspondence. My error was in the indexing in my definition of $v_{1k}$. In their paper, they define

$$v_{1k} := \lfloor \frac{d(P'|P) - k\Phi(1,1)}{p} \rfloor.$$

I misunderstood  the definition of $\Phi(1, 1)$ due to losing track of a sneaky index shift. My error was in thinking that $\Phi(1, j) = v_{P_j}(x^2)$. In their notation, $$\Phi(1,j) =v_{P_{j-1}}(x^2),$$ where $j$ is the point $P$ considered in the field $E_j$ (where we are considering the $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ extension $F/E$ as a series of $n$ successive $\mathbb{Z}/p$ extensions $$E = E_0 \subset E_1 \subset \cdots \subset F=E_n.$$

Thus, $\Phi(1,1) = -v_{P}(x^2)= 2$, and $$v_{1k} := \lfloor \frac{d(P'|P) + kv_{P}(x^2)}{p} \rfloor.$$

This resolves the issue entirely.